# Realtime Data augmentation in Lasagne

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lasagne, nolearn

I need to do realtime augmentation on my dataset for input to CNN, but i am having a really tough time finding suitable libraries for it. I have tried `caffe` but the `DataTransform` doesn't support many realtime augmentations like rotating etc. So for ease of implementation i settled with `Lasagne`. But it seems that it also doesn't support realtime augmentation. I have seen some posts related to `Facial Keypoints detection` where he's using `Batchiterator` of `nolearn.lasagne`. But i am not sure whether its realtime or not. There's no proper tutorial for it. So finally how should i do realtime augmentation in `Lasagne` either through `nolearn` or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Keras framework](http://keras.io) for real time data augmentation for CNN training. [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py) is the example code for CIFAR10 dataset from github. You can also change it to adapt your needs or copy source code and add to lasagne project but I have  not tried  importing to lasagne before. Basic idea behind this is randomly augmenting data in every batch. If you have for loop of batches that fits network, you can call your augmentation function before sending data to network.

Comment: This answer is not about Lasagne

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do real-time data augmentation in Lasagne. The simplest way is using the [GaussianNoiseLayer](http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/noise.html#lasagne.layers.GaussianNoiseLayer). Simply insert it after your input layer. If Gaussian noise is not what you need, then at least you have GaussianNoiseLayer as an example for how to implement your own.

Note how the `deterministic` parameter is used in Lasagne. It is off by default, and so during training the noise is added. During testing you set `deterministic=True` and the augmentation is simply avoided.

Comment: You could to the realtime augmentation with nolearn's `BatchIterator` in Lasagne. Earlier(while posting) the problem was the restriction of number of realtime functions we could associate with the iterator. I found a pretty decent way to solve this. Will update it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Facial Keypoints Recognition](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/) tutorial that you mention does use real-time (on the fly) augmentation to flip the input images (and target coordinates) at random.

The [nolearn-utils](https://github.com/felixlaumon/nolearn_utils/blob/master/nolearn_utils/iterators.py) library has a ton of examples of iterators that do several types of augmentation.  E.g. `AffineTransformBatchIteratorMixin` does random affine transforms on the fly.